# Can localStrage and/or indexedDb be used in a chrome extension to store data independently of the visited website?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage, indexeddb

In a Google Chrome extension, is it possible to use localStorage and indexedDb to store data independently of the visited website? And if so, is it possible to store it even after the browser has been closed?

For an example, the user would save a text in the extension when visiting www.site1.com, browse and/or close Google Chrome, then access its data again on www.site2.com.

Comment: Consider using [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) for persisting data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. I am currently working on an extension which saves the data using indexed DB. You can store the data on the background page, i.e. background page should contain scripts to create, retrieve and delete the data. Data can be send to background page using content scripts.